# XML Viewer Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to display XML data as HTML in SharePoint Online. I am not able to see the XML viewer web part (under Content Rollup Categories) even after the custom script is enabled using the admin interface. Am I missing something in configuration?

Could you please suggest any pointers or an alternative solution for displaying XML using XSLT?

Please note: I am new to SharePoint Online & SharePoint Ecosystem.

Thank you very much in advance for your support

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, external XSLT file injection to Web Part has been retired by Microsoft not long ago in SharePoint Online.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Allen. The screenshot on the right side is which web part? Is it an XML viewer? Can we still see this web part in SharePoint Online? Do you know any alternative solution for displaying XML using XSLT in SharePoint Online? Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: This is a list view web part, still can see it. I'm afraid there is no alternative in SharePoint Online currently.